# Graphics broken after 4.2.0-27 update

Tags: grub2, nvidia, kernel, graphics, live-usb

I was using Ubuntu 15.10, driver nvidia 358 from graphics-drivers PPA, my discrete card is GT-650M.

Some time after said update, I had some ugly poligons and horizontal lines on my notebook, and everything froze. It booted on Gallium, and I tried to reinstall Nvidia, but problem only become worse, and now every time I boot, I get a frozen blank, white or not so nice coloured screen.

Now, my objective is to do a clean reinstall.

I tried to boot Ubuntu 15.10 x64 from UEFI live usb, but the same screen appears, and it freezes. When I put nomodeset option, Ubuntu boots, but screen is so teared and distorced up that I cannot proceed with installation. Emergency and recovery mode works well. Xsafe does not. Antergos live freezes on loading Gnome, but no strange screen.

I'm on my cellphone, but I'l try to provide as much information as possible.

May any option besides nomodeset fix my screen (or force external monitor) and allow me to boot live usb (forcing Intel graphics)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from the Ubuntu USB installation media you have created.
Highlight Try Ubuntu without installing - press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Live desktop.
Click on Install Ubuntu to start the installation.

When finished boot into the installed Ubuntu operating system.
Highlight the Ubuntu GRUB menu entry - press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into Ubuntu system.
Now install the NVIDIA drivers and reboot ...

Comment: Hi, cl-netbox, sorry being late and the offtopic, but I managed to install Arch from the CLI only 3 AM today, and for a unknown reason, looks like it solved my live boot problem, because live Ubuntu did not freeze and I just installed Ubuntu succefully. But... it is using Gallium again, and I`m afraid that I will reproduce the same problem by installing nvidia. Is there any way to test if my graphics card is dead or faulty before installing nvidia again? Thank you!

Comment: @rmagnelli : Your graphics card most likely is not faulty - it is a compatibility thing with the open source nouveau drivers. When you use the parameter nouveau.modeset=0 and follow exactly the instructions given in my answer (part 2), you will get the NVIDIA drivers installed successfully ! :)

Comment: Sorry being late, again, took a walk between ArchLinux and antergos, but could not make bumblebee work, so I made the most non-innovative choice, and came back to LTS Ubuntu nvidia-only, as it was working 5/5 before. Graphics card is indeed not dead, and working, thank you!